# ASP .NET Panels visible true/false working only after double clicking in breakpoint mode

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, panels

I have a strange problem. There are two panels in my Page. On click of a button one becomes visible and other gets hidden. Following is my code.

```
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlIDProof" runat="server" Visible="true">
     ID Proof Panel markup here......
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlRegister" runat="server" Visible="false">
     Registration Panel markup here.....
    </asp:Panel>

   protected void btnIDCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (candidate.IsDuplicateIDProof())
            CallExist();
        else
            CallRegistration();
    }        


       protected void CallRegistration()
        {
            pnlIDProof.Visible = false;
            pnlRegister.Visible = true;
            Session["Candidate"] = candidate;
        }
```

My problem is even though the above code is getting executed, panel switching is not happening. Panel switching is happening only when I insert a breakpoint near **CallRegistration()** method and double click my button (Note that on single click it's not working). Strange thing is, without breakpoint any no.of times I click on the button, it's not happening. Not sure what could be the problem. I am using bootstrap 4.

Comment: Can we see the markup for the button itself?

Comment: Hi, here it is  <asp:Button ID="btnIDCheck" runat="server" Text="Proceed" OnClick="btnIDCheck_Click" />

Comment: And you've verified that candidate.IsDuplicateIDProof() is false? Maybe an existing value for it is held in session?

Comment: Yes, my database is empty right now. CallRegistration is also getting called, but it works only when I insert a breakpoint and double click on my ID Check Button.

Comment: Have you tried running it without the debugger? It works for me and switches panel. It stays on that panel if I refresh but that is because the state of candidate is being held in session as false. As expected. As regards hitting the button twice, maybe something amiss with your PostBack in Page Load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, found out the problem. Both my Panels are inside an UpdatePanel, visible true/false is not working because there are some javascript errors in the page. I am debbuging my application in Chrome, when I tried debugging in Internet explorer javascipt errors popped up. After correcting the Javascipt errors, page works fine.